# MapKitでピンをタップした際にtitleを取得したい

Tags: swift, swift2, mapkit

題名の通りです。

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let title = annotation.title

}
```

これだと毎回アノテーションを生成するのでnilになってしまいますよね。
正しいtitleの取得方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let annotation = view.annotation
    let title = annotation.title
    ...

}
```

選択したビューが２番目の引数に渡ってきているので、その`annotation`プロパティにアクセスすると選択したアノテーションが取得できます。

それの`title`プロパティです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事実装できました。